# Sklearn Library in Google CoLab

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Google CoLab contains most of the vanilla ML libraries such as numpy and matplotlib by default. However, while we import many such default libraries, we do not import the sklearn library. Why is that?

Comment: when i do 'import sklearn' it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to install any packages that is not by default existing in the Google CoLab, you can install them like this:

> !pip install
> package_name

So for scikit learn, you can do as follows:

> !pip install
> scikit-learn